# Extending the UI in Outlook 2010 by means of HTML or somthink like this for rendering web page

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am looking for a way to extend user interface in Outlook 2010 with a help of HTML or somthing like on HTML IFRAME as on the following picture.
I want to know if it is possible or I must create the whole interface by means of Fluent UI as said in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_BackstageView)
[image]
**Update**:
**Solved**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create an Outlook Task Pane - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb296010.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thank you for help! But may be you know how a can create TaskPane with Ribbon type Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer (like on a picture) because a have a some trouble with this case (see update)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "TaskPane with Ribbon type". You cannot insert your pane on top of a built-in Outlook pane if that is what you mean.